# C++ efficient parsing of a Python array string

Tags: python, c++, arrays, regex

I have a file created from a series of Python arrays.  I am loading it from an `ifstream`.
The file is text and contains nothing but the arrays.  It is of the form:

```
[[1 22 333 ... 9
  2 2 2    ... 2]
 ...    
 [5 6 2 ... 222
  5 5 5 ... 240]]

[[2 3 444 ... 9]
 ...    
 [5 6 2 ... 222
  5 5 5 ... 240]]

[[ etc...
```

Each row of each array starts with `[` and ends with `]` but may be broken onto several lines within the file (i.e., has carriage returns or line breaks within the open and close `[]`.
An entire array starts and ends with brackets `[]`.

The type of number will always be integer.  The number of entries in each row (i.e., the number of columns) will be the same for every row of a particular array, but that number may differ between different arrays.  The number of rows in an array is not known and may differ between arrays.  And the total number of arrays per file is also not known before opening the file.

The arrays can be stored in whatever format.  For the sake of this example, let's put them in a vector of vectors of vectors, i.e.,

```
typedef vector<vector<int>> myArray;  //Index [row][col]
typedef vector<myArray> myArrays;
```

I would like to parse this efficiently (potentially very large files, most probably many files). My boss is very keen on using `std::regex` for this, which I am comfortable with so long as it is efficient.

So my question is: how can I parse this efficiently with regex.  And would there be a way to parse it significantly more efficiently without regex?

Comment: `std::regex` is usually the slowest way you can do such things. Please ban the combination *parsing + regex* from your mind.
Do you have access to the Python sources? The easiest way would be to change the output on the Python side and use a structured format that is well supported in C++.

Comment: @dtell - fair enough.  That's why I asked the question.  It was my boss' idea, and that's what I'm trying to ascertain.  There is no option to change the files or the way they are output from Python.

Comment: I don't really understand the down rates for this post.  How could I have better written the question, or what detail could have been added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::from_chars()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) is efficient since it analyses a portion of string in-place and tells exactly where the analysis ended, so that you can go on right after without extracting substrings.
Moreover, the note in the documentation says:

> Unlike other parsing functions in C++ and C libraries, std::from_chars
> is locale-independent, non-allocating, and non-throwing. Only a small
> subset of parsing policies used by other libraries (such as
> std::sscanf) is provided. This is intended to allow the fastest
> possible implementation that is useful in common high-throughput
> contexts such as text-based interchange (JSON or XML).

Here is an attempt to parse your data.

```
/**
  g++ -std=c++17 -o prog_cpp prog_cpp.cpp \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <charconv>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

using MyRow = std::vector<int>;
using MyArray = std::vector<MyRow>;

std::vector<MyArray>
parse_arrays(std::istream &input_stream)
{
  auto arrays=std::vector<MyArray>{};
  auto line=std::string{};
  for(auto depth=0, line_count=1;
      std::getline(input_stream, line);
      ++line_count)
  {
    for(const auto *first=data(line), *last=first+size(line);
        first!=last;)
    {
      // try first to consume all well known characters
      for(auto c=*first; std::isspace(c)||(c=='[')||(c==']'); c=*(++first))
      {
        switch(c)
        {
          case '[': // opening a row or an array
          {
            switch(++depth)
            {
              case 1:
              {
                arrays.emplace_back(MyArray{});
                break;
              }
              case 2:
              {
                arrays.back().emplace_back(MyRow{});
                break;
              }
              default:
              {
                const auto pfx="line "+std::to_string(line_count);
                throw std::runtime_error{pfx+": too deep"};
              }
            }
            break;
          }
          case ']': // closing a row or an array
          {
            switch(--depth)
            {
              case 0:
              {
                // nothing more to be done
                break;
              }
              case 1:
              {
                const auto &a=arrays.back();
                const auto sz=size(a);
                if((sz>1)&&(size(a[sz-1])!=size(a[sz-2])))
                {
                  const auto pfx="line "+std::to_string(line_count);
                  throw std::runtime_error{pfx+": row length mismatch"};
                }
                break;
              }
              default:
              {
                const auto pfx="line "+std::to_string(line_count);
                throw std::runtime_error{pfx+": ] mismatch"};
              }
            }
            break;
          }
          default: // a separator
          {
            // nothing more to be done
          }
        }
      }
      // the other characters probably represent an integer
      auto value=int{};
      if(auto [p, ec]=std::from_chars(first, last, value); ec==std::errc())
      {
        if(depth!=2)
        {
          const auto pfx="line "+std::to_string(line_count);
          throw std::runtime_error{pfx+": depth mismatch"};
        }
        arrays.back().back().emplace_back(value);
        first=p;
      }
      else
      {
        if(p!=first)
        {
          const auto pfx="line "+std::to_string(line_count);
          throw std::runtime_error{pfx+": integer out of range"};
        }
        else if(first!=last)
        {
          const auto pfx="line "+std::to_string(line_count);
          throw std::runtime_error{pfx+": unexpected char <"+*first+'>'};
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return arrays;
}

int
main()
{
  auto input=std::istringstream{R"(
[[1 22 333  9
  2 2 2     2]
     
 [5 6 2  222
  5 5 5  240]]

[[2 3 444  9]
     
 [5 6 2  222]]
)"};
  const auto arrays=parse_arrays(input);
  for(const auto &a: arrays)
  {
    for(const auto &r: a)
    {
      for(const auto &c: r)
      {
        std::cout << c << ' ';
      }
      std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";
  }
  return 0;
}

/**
1 22 333 9 2 2 2 2 
5 6 2 222 5 5 5 240 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 3 444 9 
5 6 2 222 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
**/
```